# PHPExcel Warning/Error when opening document

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have built an Excel document using the PHPExcel Library. My document opens and looks fine both in Numbers (mac) and Office 2007 (windows). I am saving my file as a .xlsx file.

When I open the file, although it displays properly, it gives the following errors/warnings.

In Numbers, it gives the warning "**Password protection on sheets isn't supported and was removed**"

In Office 2007 it gives te error "**Excel found unreadable content in 'filename.xlsx'. Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.**" When I click yes, everything displays fine, and it says "**Removed Records: Merge cells from /sl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part**".

It should be noted that I did not add any password to my file. I also have only one workbook. Anyone know how I can get rid of these or what might be causing them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've had the same problem and i resolved simply putting an

```
exit();
```

justafter the `$objWriter->save('php://output');` command.

Eg.

```
// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel2007)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="industrializzazione_RTW_'.$rows[0]['stagione'].'.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007'); 
$objWriter->save('php://output'); 
exit();
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into something similar while using CakePHP building a spreadsheet with mergecells.  It works fine for Excel 2003 but not Excel 2007 format.  If I build the 2007 spreadsheet using:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('C30:E30');
```

the spreadsheet loads fine.  However using a variable in any way such as these variants:

```
$mergestr = '\'C'.(30+$i).':E'.(30+$i).'\'';
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells($mergestr);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells(eval("return \$$mergestr;"));
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('\'C'.(30+$i).':E'.(30+$i).'\'');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->mergeCells('C'.(30+$i).':E'.(30+$i));
```

I get the same error you do.  I'm not sure if there is a way to escape a variable in a way PHPExcel will like for the Excel2007 writer.  The Excel5 writer works fine with the last example above.  Hope this helps someone.